# PHP get user ID

Tags: php, mysql, session

So I'm pretty new to PHP and I'm following [this](https://htmlcssphptutorial.wordpress.com/2015/07/07/simple-user-registration-login-script-in-php-and-mysql/comment-page-1/#comment-238) tutorial, which teachers how to make a login/register system using PHP. On the Index page, it echos the user's username using `$_SESSION['username'];`. I want to see if you can display the user ID or the user email. I tried replacing the code with `$_SESSION['id'];`, but it didn't work.

Comment: only username is put in a session in that code, if you want other values in a session you have to add them. please post relevant code here, dont link to it, its liable to get the question closed

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to use that article as an example at all. No one should be using functions start with `mysql_` it's deprecated in PHP 5.5.0

Comment: Also this is a dangerously dated tutorial using many bad practices, you should find something newer

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. This tutorial is severely outdated and should not be used. Remember, any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), as used in this tutorial, is so awful awful it has been removed in PHP 7.

Answer (score 0):

**while this is an answer there are so many bad approaches in this code it should not be followed (your call)**

```
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $username = stripslashes($username);
 $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
 $password = stripslashes($password);
 $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
 //Checking is user existing in the database or not
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and password='".md5($password)."'";
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
 if($rows==1){
 $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

the only thing added to `$_SESSION` is username, but you can add any value you have, in this case you do have the variables from the database so:

```
 $_SESSION['email'] = $results['email'];
```

you can do the same with any other db value you have.

Comment: `stripslashes()` is not needed anymore. Magic quotes were removed from PHP 7. Anyway, if you target PHP 5, `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` should be checked first.